# Exporting Multiple grid to Single excel Sheet using Kendo

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I have a scenario where i have to export data to excel, which am able to do using Kendo UI Excel Export. But there is an requirement to export multiple table to same excel sheet which am not able to achieve. It would be great if anyone can help in this. Please find below code which am using to push single table to excel sheet.

```
CreateWorkSheets: function(headerArrayLength, rows, SheetName){
        var columnWidth = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < headerArrayLength; i++) {
            columnWidth.push({ autoWidth : true });
        }
        oKendo.Constants.workSheets.push({ 
            columns: columnWidth,
            // Title of the sheet
            title: SheetName,
              // Rows of the sheet
            rows: rows
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using [manual Excel exports](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/excel-export#excel-customization)?

Basically you need to setup two seperate arrays (for each sheet), then setup a new `kendo.ooxml.Workbook` containing an array of `sheets`, one for each grid dataSource.

Here is a [Dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/axuYO/5), the two grids are identical but the functionality just needs modified to fit your needs.